# Converting double to time(hours and Minute)

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to program in VBA i am stuck with a small conversion , I have an input data as "double", I have another 2 value as in time format . I want to add this double in time format and out put as time

```
Totalhours  = 99  (double)
Starttime = 00:30:00 (hh:mm:ss)
Endtime = 00:30:00 (hh:mm:ss)
Result = 100 hours
```

I want to add Totalhours+Starttime +Endtime in a time format . I tried all possible way i didnt get the answer.

Code:

```
 Totalinthrs = Int(Nuday * Worksheets("qwer").Range("C2").Value)
 Totalhours = Int(Totalinthrs + Starttime)
 Totalhours = Totalinthrs * 24
 Worksheets("qwer").Range("C5").Value = TotHours
 Totalhours = CDate(Totalhours)
 Totalhours = TimeValue(Totalhours)
 Totalhours = TotHours + Starttime + Endtime
```

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path but over-complicating...

```
Result = TotalHours + ((StartTime + EndTime) * 24)
```

gives a `Result` of `100`.